# Upgrading to php 8.1 breaks some each code

Tags: php, upgrade

I have some code...

```
while (list($key, $val) = @each($_POST)) { $val = addslashes($val); $GLOBALS[$key] = $val; }
while (list($key, $val) = @each($_GET)) { $val = addslashes($val); $GLOBALS[$key] = $val; }
```

On upgrading to 8.1 it causes the following error...

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in Path to file
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in path to file
```

Could anyone help me with what I need to alter please?

Thank you

Comment: In PHP8 `each` is deprecated, you have to change it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388435

Comment: Read and inwardly digest [Migrating from PHP 8.0.x to PHP 8.1.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration81.php) Prefereably before doing the upgrade

Comment: Instead of `while (list($key, $val) = @each($_POST)) {`, try `foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {`. That should get you back on track.

Comment: Guido, thank you so much that works a treat! really greatful